# Manipulating page bookmark position

Tags: javascript, html, twitter-bootstrap

I'm using Bootstrap to create a single page portfolio, I'm using bookmark links to navigate the page, however I want the page to land earlier than the position it lands on, I am pointing to the div I assigned the Id to it. is there anyway to do it?

Answer (score 0):

Let's say, you want to go to footer on click of **Goto Footer** link

```
<a href="#footer-block">Goto Footer</a>
```

Then, the footer block should have

```
<div id="footer-block">Page Footer</div>
```

Comment: Thank you Nobal.

I know that part, what I want is the page to stop before the exact div border. Hopefully the screenshots will make it more clear.

[before][1]
[after][2]


  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/tO5wM.jpg
  [2]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/mAPMo.jpg

Comment: Then change the ID to some inner DIV. I think in your case, the ID is in the out most DIV. Move the anchor ID to "Continuing Education .." and check